# auto feeding content from another pages container to a div

Tags: php, ajax, parsing, curl

I am currently trying to stream the content located on http://store.kenstanton.net/Default.asp the five images located just above the featured videos

and stream it to http://www.kenstanton.net to the content (currently the same atm however I would like to be able to update one webpage and have the following update as well) above the featured videos on that page.

I'm currently trying to use an ajaxpagefetch script if thats the appropriate route our should I `curl` it and then parse?

Comment: DO you need to display the content on initial page load, or are you trying to add the content to the page after the initial load?

Comment: If you have better access to the originating code, then you should probably make use of it. Even creating a mini responder on the www domain would probably be better than scraping. If these sites are hosted on the same host then you could make the connection even deeper.

Comment: trying to display on initial load

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is probably the way to go - you might want to look at [jQuery manual for .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments). In your case it'd be something like:

```
$('#result').load('http://store.kenstanton.net/Default.asp .v65-productDisplay');
```

But of course there might be some styling issues as well as AJAX security restrictions (of those I'm not sure, but writing simple redirector should do the trick in such case)